# Web design company backlinking technique

Tags: seo

I own a small web design company and most of our backlinks come from having a link on our client sites, I am just wondering what is the best method of including a link on each clients website.

Currently we tend to use:

Web Design by **Company Name**

and link on the company name. Occasionally we mix this up a little by doing something like:

**Property Website by Company Name**

and link on the whole sentence. We always do sitewide links at the moment.

Is this a good method? Should we only be linking on one page maybe? (homepage?) any thoughts are much appreciated.

Edit: I know similar has been asked before in this thread: [Web designers back link on client sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19590/web-designers-back-link-on-client-sites?rq=1) but as SEO has changed a lot in the last year I think it's valid to ask this again.

Comment: I'll bump the old thread up for you and hopefully your get some responses.

Comment: Also left an answer for you.